# IIS Dynamic Compression and ASP.NET Core

Tags: asp.net-core, iis, compression

I have an ASP.NET Core v2.2 application deployed to IIS. I'm following the recommendation of using IIS dynamic compression rather than the response compression middleware as stated in [Response compression in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/performance/response-compression?view=aspnetcore-2.2). I used the IIS Management Tool to configure the dynamic compression in IIS and it's working as expected. However, this updates the application's web.config to include a urlCompression element.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
    <system.webServer>
      <handlers>
        <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModuleV2" resourceType="Unspecified" />
      </handlers>
      <aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" arguments=".\xyz.dll" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" hostingModel="InProcess" />
    </system.webServer>
  </location>
    <system.webServer>
        <urlCompression doDynamicCompression="true" />
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

My issue is that the next time I publish the application the dynamic compression setting is lost and I have to go back into the IIS Management Tool to configure it again.

How do I ensure this setting is preserved after re-publishing my application and without having to go into the IIS Management Tool every time?

Is there a way to include this dynamic compression setting in the Visual Studio project so it's included in the generated web.config file?

Answer (score 1):

You can create a "web.config" file in the root of your project, and the contents will be merged with the other generated content in the resulting "web.config" file after publishing.

Example project file:

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <urlCompression doDynamicCompression="true" />
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Contents of "web.config" file at the published location:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <urlCompression doDynamicCompression="true" />
    <handlers>
      <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModuleV2" resourceType="Unspecified" />
    </handlers>
    <aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" arguments=".\xxx.dll" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" hostingModel="inprocess" />
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```